# Adding and removing bitmap images with mouse "click" - JavaScript / CreateJS

Tags: javascript, html, bitmap, containers, easeljs

I am adding coins (bitmaps) to some containers(10 containers alltogether) when I click them. Now I want to remove the coins one after another. For example if I click 3 times on a Shape on my stage than I create 3 coins and put them into a container. Now if I click one time on the remove button (also on the stage) it should remove the last coin added to the container and so on.

Here is how I attempted it:
-->"evt.target" is a container

```
this.coin= new createjs.Bitmap(images.jeton_image);
this.coin.value = this.coin_index;
this.coin_array.push(this.coin);
this.coin_index++;
this.coin.regX = 50;
this.coin.regY = 50;
evt.target.addChild(this.jetons);
this.target_arr.push(evt.target);
```

Now here is how I would remove the coins:

```
this.target_arr[this.target_arr.length].removeChild(this.coin);
```

My problem is that I can not remove the coins from the 10 containers.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "I can not remove the coins from the 10 containers."  I didn't get much what that means ?

Comment: I have 10 Shapes on the stage and for every shape a container. So if I click on the first shape the coin is added to the first container and so on. I hope you understand now what I mean by my question.

Comment: and I suppose the problem is you are not able to remove the coins sequentially, right?

Comment: Yes that is my problem because I can click on the first shape and than on the third  or on the last one.

Comment: ok clear now it not seen from your code what this.target_arr refer to ?

Comment: My ideea was to put the containers into an array depending on how I clicked on them and than get tha las container from this array and removing its children.

Comment: this.target_arr is an array where I stored all the containers I clicked

Comment: try this.target_arr[this.target_arr.length-1].removeChild(this.coin); cause your array position would never bee in the length considering the fact that they start by 0

Comment: @ яша hey it works only for the last one and not for the others

Comment: the problem is that this works only for the last clicked shape. I do not know how to get to the other containers I clicked before that

Comment: try to see if my solution is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see here is that the problem is residing in the position of the array index you are trying to manipulate:

**First Stage**

if you use push to add this data to your Array, data would be added to the end of the index

let's say:

```
var a=[]; //a.length would be 0 and you can't position any index inside
```

now when you push some data to it:

```
 a.push(1);//a.length=1
    [ 1 ]
      ^
index:0    
    a.push(2);//a.length=2
    [ 1 , 2 ]
      ^   ^
index:0   1 
    a.push(3);//a.length=3
    [ 1, 2, 3 ]
      ^  ^  ^
index:0  1  2 //when trying to make that a[a.length]  
              //would give error as the maximum position 
              //reside in the index 2 not 3
```

so this :

```
this.target_arr[this.target_arr.length].removeChild(this.coin);
```

should be this instead:

```
this.target_arr[this.target_arr.length-1].removeChild(this.coin);
```

**Second stage**

what you are missing is :

```
this.coin_array.pop(this.coin);
this.target_arr.pop(evt.target);
```

To remove the latest element when removing your child node to **shrink** the array 
cause in the memory your Array is still composed of 10 elements, so you should shrink it by poping up the latest element concurrently while removing the image

Comment: thank you so much you saved my day :) I was struggling with this for some time. Now it works perfectly!

Comment: if that helped you please vote up, I guess you are elligible of voting up now :)